# Как применить стиль к дочернему элементу, но не применять его к внуку?

Tags: css

есть блок, внутри которого есть два одноименных блока, только один находится непосредственно внутри родительского, а второй имеет еще несколько оберток.
Как применить стиль только к дочернему "сын"?

```css
.cild {
  background: #CDDC39;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class='parrent'>
  <div class='cild'>сын</div>
  <div class='folder'>
    <div class='cild'>внук</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: .parrent>.cild {

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь работает выборка через `>` (только первый уровень наследников).

Это делается так:

```
.parrent > .cild {

}
```

[Документация о селекторах](https://learn.javascript.ru/css-selectors)

Comment: Я русский язык поправил, но лучше совсем убрать второе предложение :)

Comment: @splash58 ух, это я конечно ошибся так ошибся, спасибо. Когда писал почему-то не задумался об этом, и ошибку вроде увидел, но не исправил. Вечер близится :)